# How can i filter a datetime column using a where clause

Tags: sql-server-express

I need to filter a datetime column which is named Departure.

I need the filter to return all prices <=100 and where the departure date is between 2105-03-14 and 2015-03-17 and the departure time on these dates is from 1pm onwards.

I tried the code below. The joins work properly but the where clause is the problem. Can anyone help.

```
Select Destination,Departure,Price
From PriceTable as p
Join Routes as r
On p.RouteID = r.ID
Join Destinations as d
On d.Airport_ICAO_Code = r.Airport_ICAO_Code
Where (Price <= 100) And (Departure between '2015-03-14' and '2015-03-17' >= '13:00:00') 
Order by Price Asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right syntax to filter the records after some `xx:xx:xx` time. Try this `where` clause

```
.....
.....
WHERE  Price <= 100
       AND Departure BETWEEN '2015-03-14' AND '2015-03-17'
       AND CONVERT(TIME, Departure) >= '13:00:00'
.....
```